# Raising a number to a power; Repeating words

Tags: java, methods, repeat, exponent

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class ZhangIDK
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("Please enter a number");
        int h = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println ("Please enter another number");
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println ("Please enter a string/word");
        String j = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println ("Please enter a number");
        int k = sc.nextInt();
        average (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
        least (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    }

    public static void average (int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g)
    {
        int y = a + b + c + d + e + f + g;
        y/=7;
        System.out.println (y);
    }

    public static void least (int q, int r, int s, int t, int u)
    {
        int Smallestnumber = 100;
        int number = 1;
        if (number < Smallestnumber)
        {
            Smallestnumber = number;
            number++;
        }
        System.out.println("The smallest number is" +Smallestnumber+ ".");
    }

    public static void power (int h, int i)
    {

    }

    public static void repeater (String j, int k)
    {

    }
}
```

In our programming class, we're learning about methods.  Our teacher assigned us this thing where in the first method, we found the average of 7 (pre declared) numbers, in the second method, we found the smallest number of 5 (pre declared) numbers.  In the third method, we have to use a scanner to input two numbers and the first number is raised to the power of the second number.  Ex: 5, 2; the program should output 25 (5^2).  And finally, in the fourth method, we have to use a scanner again and enter a string and a number and the program should output the string the amount of the times as the number.  Ex:Bill, 3; the computer would output, Bill  Bill  Bill.

I'm having trouble with the third and fourth methods. In my power method, when I enter, for example, 2 and 4, the program simply prints out the 2.  Also, when I try to do the fourth method, well thats flat out not working for some reason, though it looks like it should work fine.  One thing is that the part where its system.out.println the question "Please enter a work" and "Please enter a number" the two questions come together in one chunk so I have no way of entering a word.  Please HELP!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think in a homework assignment it is allowed to use `Math.pow` here.

These two methods have something in common, that they are both capable of being implemented using a [`for`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop) loop

```
public static void power (int h, int i){
    int result = 1; //If i == 0 then h^i == 1

    for (int tmp=0; tmp<i; tmp++){
        result *= h
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}

public static void repeater (String j, int k){
    for(int tmp = 0; tmp<k; tmp++){
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: if what's being taught is methods, Math.pow() in one might be okay.  Still, it's best for the poster to learn both ways of writing the power.

Comment: Yeah, given that it is a pretty trivial method here I thought that maybe they want the students to implement it by themselves. :)

Comment: I tried Albus Shin's answer but when I raised, for example, 2 to the 4, the program just printed out 2.  Any suggestions as to why?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void power (int h, int i)
{
    System.out.println(Math.pow(h, i));
}
```

Math.pow() is a standard library function for raising a number to a power.

```
public static void repeater (String j, int k)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) System.out.println(j);
}
```

What this does is, for each value between 0 and k-1, print the string j.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void power(int h, int i){
            System.out.print(Math.pow(h, i));
        }

        public static void repeater(String name, int count){
            for(int i = 1; i<=count; i++){
                System.out.print(name+" ");
            }
```

In java, getting power of numbers have already been taking care of, instead of running a loop that multiplies the number by itself. to use the function you need to call the `Math.pow`

As you can see above, the Math.pow() takes to integer inputs(or double), the first input which is the main number and the second which is the power...

talking about the printing of strings repeatedly.. i am sure you must have done loops else i am not sure you would really understand what's going up dere...but it is very straight forward...there is nothing to explain there...